# Cannot iterate through days past the end of year in Golang's Time package

Tags: datetime, go

I'm trying to iterate through days between 2 dates. One date is `time.Parse("2006-01-02", "2017-08-24")` another is `time.Now()` but my loop seems to be stopping at the turn of the year and I can't figure out why.

```
func IsToday(date time.Time) bool {
    today := time.Now()
    return date.Year() == today.Year() &&
           date.Month() == today.Month() &&
           date.Day() == date.Day()
}

t1, _ := time.Parse("2006-01-02", "2017-08-24")

for curr := t1; !IsToday(curr); curr = curr.AddDate(0,0,1) {
        fmt.Println(curr)
}
```

The loop prints out:

```
2017-08-24 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
2017-08-25 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
2017-08-26 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
2017-08-27 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
2017-08-28 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
2017-08-29 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
2017-08-30 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
2017-08-31 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
2017-09-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
2017-09-02 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
...
2017-12-18 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
2017-12-19 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
2017-12-20 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
2017-12-21 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
2017-12-22 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
2017-12-23 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
2017-12-24 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
2017-12-25 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
2017-12-26 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
2017-12-27 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
2017-12-28 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
2017-12-29 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
2017-12-30 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
2017-12-31 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
```

Notice how it does not iterate till today's date. Testing the AddDate individually as `time.Parse("2006-01-02", "2017-12-31").AddDate(0,0,1)` does result in `2018-01-01`.

Comment: You have a typo in your `IsDate` function: `date.Day() == date.Day()` should be `date.Day() == today.Day()`.

Comment: @muistooshort Can't believe I did that, spent way too much time debugging. Thank you for the catch

Comment: The trickiest bugs are often hiding right out in the open, hence the "fresh eyes" and "talking to the wall" debugging techniques.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculate tomorrow's date and iterate while `curr` is before that date:

```
now := time.Now()
tomorrow := time.Date(now.Year(), now.Month(), now.Day(), 0, 0, 0, 0, now.Location()).AddDate(0, 0, 1)
for curr := t1; curr.Before(tomorrow); curr = curr.AddDate(0, 0, 1) {
    fmt.Println(curr)
}
```

Iterating while `!IsToday(curr)` (with typo corrected) is fragile because it will loop forever if the starting time is after the current time.

Comment: This is better, I'll switch to it. Wouldn't you be able to simplify tommorow to `tommorow := time.Now().AddDate(0,0,1)`

Comment: The goal is to calculate the time af beginning of the day.  The expression `time.Now().AddDate(0,0,1)` evaluates to the current time tomorrow.